# Adding an Individual JSON Object to an Array to Parse and Process

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following json object samples, i.e.:

```
 {"id":"value1" , "time":"valuetime1"}
 {"id":"value2" , "time":"valuetime2"}
 {"id":"value3" , "time":"valuetime3"}
 {"id":"value4" , "time":"valuetime4"}
 {"id":"value5" , "time":"valuetime5"}
 {"id":"value6" , "time":"valuetime6"}
 {"id":"value7" , "time":"valuetime7"}
 {"id":"value8" , "time":"valuetime8"}
```

Based on the above, I would like to add all these json objects to an array, where I can then process and access the array for each json object and extract id1 value together with time1 value and so forth.

I believe I have to use **JSON.parse** but unsure of how to firstly add these objects to an array and then be able to also parse and access each object's data.

Think of each row above as a separate JSON object which I would like added to an array that is parsed.

Comment: Question is not clear.. Input seems wrong to me...

Comment: you can edit the file firstly with an editor or script that'll make this an Array of JSON and yes JSON.parse can be used when you are sure the value is of type JSON

Comment: Why are you using id1, id2, and time1, time2? Property names should usually be the same.

Comment: I basically would like to take each json object, parse it and add it to an array for processing. Property names are different b/c they relate to different records from a database table.

Comment: Just to be clear, these objects are in the form of a file you are reading in, or a string which is coming in from somewhere? Or are they just regular old JS objects available to your program that you want to put into an array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Appreciate the responses but I believe I have managed to solve my own question.

Furthermore, as @Mr. White mentioned above, I did have my property names in error which I have now sorted - thanks.

Using the data above, all I was after was the following:

**UPDATED**

```
var s =  '{"id":"value1","time":"valuetime1"},{"id":"value2","time":"valuetime2"},{"id":"value3","time":"valuetime3"},{"id":"value4","time":"valuetime4"},{"id":"value5","time":"valuetime5"}, {"id":"value6","time":"valuetime6"},{"id":"value7","time":"valuetime7"},{"id":"value8","time":"valuetime8"}';

var a = JSON.parse('[' + s + ']');

a.forEach(function(item,i){
  console.log(item.id + ' - '+ item.time);
});
```

Thanks for the heads up @torazaburo - have updated my answer which I should've done much earlier.

Comment: Why would you stringify and then immediately parse? You'll just get back what you started with. Also, in your function, `a[i]` is precisely identical to `item`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the file line by line (each line is a separate json)
2. Parse the line json text to JavaScript object
3. Put/push/append JavaScript object into a JavaScript array

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid JSON, so JSON.parse would not work, but assuming you have the text in a string variable, you can convert it to JSON with something like:

```
data = "[" + data.replace(/\}/g, "},").replace(/,$/,"") + "]";
```

and then parse it.

UPDATE:

```
var array = [];

// for each input line

var obj = JSON.parse(line);
array.push(obj);
var id = obj.id;
var time = obj.time;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but look at each row as a separate JSON object, which I just want to add all to an array. If you take each line separately and run it through JSONLint it comes back as valid.

Comment: If this **were** a JSON-format string, which actually I don't think it is, then rather than constructing JSON with string arithmetic, it would be better to do `input.split('\n').map(JSON.parse)`.